# I want to map my array from an object using react and next.js, it's a function component using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to map my array. The array is in an object like this:

```
const data = {data: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
page: 2,
per_page: 6,
total: 12,
total_pages: 2}
```

I'm trying to be cool and use react hooks for the state, react function component and next.js.
Everything works except this mapping of the array. I can even print out the data.data.length, just no the array itself, any ideas?

myComponent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function UserList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  //useEffect only fires getUsers() after DOM first loads or changes
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
  async function getUsers() {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return loading ? (
    <div>...Data Loading.....</div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {data.data.map((item, i) => {
        <div>{item.first_name}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: you are not returning from `map`... `return <div>{item.name}</div>`

Comment: why are you typing `data` as `any`, initializing it as a string, then attempting to map over a property of it which may or may not exist (I can't tell because there's no type info here)? what is the shape of the object that you expect your API call to return?

Comment: oh, good catch @Dupocas. OP, you want parens around the return value of your mapping function, not curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

it was the conditional using `loading ?`, if I use `if else` method, I can return the mapped div `return <div>{item.first_name}</div>;`

```
if (loading) {
    return <div>...Data Loading.....</div>;
  } else {
    return data.data.map((item, i) => {
      return <div>{item.first_name}</div>;
    });
  }
```